# mcDropdown alternatives for multi level select boxes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I use [mcDropdown](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.htm) for my multi level select boxes, but the handling with many levels is sometimes very tricky. I wonder if there are any recommended alternatives?